# Can't assign object to session variable?

Tags: php, session, object

I am having trouble understanding why the following statement doesn't work?

```
$_SESSION['user_level'] = $member_info->user_level;
```

When I dump the session back, I only see `array([user_level] => )` so it is clearly missing the value?

I've tested the object by doing `print_r($member_info->user_level);` and it indeed returns the correct value so I know that is not the problem.

So I am stumped...Thanks...

Comment: The problem isn't with the session - the `user_level` is being set in the session object as it is being shown as `array([user_level] => )`. The problem is with the object and the variable your accessing.

Comment: What's user_level type? array?

Comment: Did you include the class definition when you check the session?

Comment: Hmmm not sure what to do...I think user_level is considered a member variable? Not sure if that is the "correct" term for it.

Comment: type means something like, string, float, integer or a certain class, mixed type. what does it say, wen you var_dump($member_info->user_level);

Comment: ok having to use var_dump helped me solved this problem and thanks to Raffael....I started seeing NULL after using it and I realize the problem was the object wasn't properly assigned at the moment the session variable was being assigned a value.  So sorry guys for wasting your time...

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved by using var_dump() instead of print_r().

Here's a comparison between var_dump, print_r and var_export:

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/1631/var_dump-print_r-var_export/p1#Discussion_1631